# CSS Screen Resolutions for multiple devices

Tags: android, html, css, windows, macos

Just created my business site, and went live for debugging tests. As usual I'm assuming. My nav, body, and footer adjust depending on what device is used.

I'm hoping there's an easy fix to create screen adjustments per the device, but I'm not sure how to. The information I've looked up all show different things.

Can someone help me with how to implement code to adjust per screen resolutions? (different computer screens, mobile devices- both iPhone and samsung, tablets, etc)

Website is: http://www.se7enservice.com

Comment: There are way too many devices and screen sizes just to pick a set of numbers and **hope** the design fits. Change the screen size until the design breaks and use that *that* as the chosen media query break point. It might be 945px, it might be 865px but it's your design...not the devices.

Comment: ok that's what I wasn't sure about. thank you

Comment: Don't refer other websites, especially not if they are business sites. It seems as if you wanted to spam.

Comment: @peterh Sorry if I wasn't clear. The site is my own business site. I posted it to show the proof of how when you view other devices, the dimensions are off

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* default styles here for older browsers. 
       I tend to go for a 600px - 960px width max but using percentages
    */
    @media only screen and (min-width:960px){
        /* styles for browsers larger than 960px; */
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width:1440px){
        /* styles for browsers larger than 1440px; */
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width:2000px){
        /* for sumo sized (mac) screens */
    }
    @media only screen and (max-device-width:480px){
       /* styles for mobile browsers smaller than 480px; (iPhone) */
    }
    @media only screen and (device-width:768px){
       /* default iPad screens */
    }
    /* different techniques for iPad screening */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
      /* For portrait layouts only */
    }

    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
      /* For landscape layouts only */
    }
</style>
```